# Cannot install Windows 10 on a very old laptop: CRITICAL_PROCESS_DIED

Tags: windows-10, bsod, windows-installation, acpi, hardware-detection

I have a **very old** laptop (based on Intel Core 2 Duo T5450) which came with Windows Vista which works on it just fine. It has 3 GB of RAM, plenty of free space and otherwise 100% functional.

I'm unable to install Windows 10, Version 21H2 on it because after the first reboot (**during installation** which requires 2 reboots), the system BSODs with the message: CRITICAL_PROCESS_DIED. This is **long before** the first time configuration wizard (Out of Box Experience).

I've tried to enable "Boot logging" but the log doesn't contain the information what and why is failing.

[image: Boot logging enabled]

Also, it seems like Windows 10 doesn't properly handle this laptop ACPI:

- Instead of rebooting, the computer keeps running albeit with a black screen and all the LEDs off;
- Instead of powering off, the screen turns dim and again, all the LEDs are off
  but the laptop keeps running.

[image: "fake" power off]

**I wonder how can I debug this further and make Windows 10 install on it.**

Please don't give me "standard" answers - I'm an IT pro with over 25 years of experience.

- I'm running the latest available BIOS version
- I've tried resetting BIOS settings
- I've run memtest86 for over 4 hours - no errors
- The HDD has been tested using badblocks, its SMART is fine
- Windows Vista and XP work just fine on it
- My installation media (USB stick) is 100% correct - I've verified all the installation files' checksums, the same media works just fine on a different PC.
- I **cannot** disable any devices in BIOS - there's **no** such option. At most I can disable network boot which is useless.
- Windows 10 obviously does **not** support this laptop GPU but Windows 10 can utilize VESA 2.0 protocol for unsupported GPUs.
- I've tried disabling the said CAD.sys (Charge Arbitration Driver) service to no avail. This laptop's battery is dead but that doesn't stop XP and Vista from working.
- I've tried to use the installation media "Fix boot errors" tool but it doesn't detect any issues.

***Again, to make it perfectly clear: I cannot complete installation**.

I suspect Windows 10 incorrectly handles this laptop ACPI but I cannot find any pertinent documentation: at least in Linux you can specify various non-standard ACPI modes, e.g. `acpi=off`, `acpi=ht`, `pci=noacpi`, `acpi=noirq`, `pnpacpi=off`, `noapic`, `nolapic`, etc.

---

**Update from 2022-03-22:**

Windows 8.1 works fine on this laptop and it does have GPU drivers - albeit the only version and it gets downloaded as part of Windows Updates. It's really upsetting it only has half a year left in it.

Comment: Boot logging shows the problem is related to the display driver (`dxgkrnl.sys`). You might need to slipstream the driver into the Windows 10 boot. What is this computer's display adapter? If the old computer is standard and known model, what is it?

Comment: @harrymc *Windows 10 obviously does **not** support this laptop GPU but Windows 10 can utilize VESA 2.0 protocol for unsupported GPUs.* I really doubt the issue is down to GPU support.

Comment: It can, but this doesn't seem to be working for that computer. Windows might be mis-identifying the adapter and dying when it gives wrong responses. It's up to you whether you wish to answer questions or not.

Comment: GPU: NVIDIA GeForce Go 7300 (it only has Windows XP/Vista drivers) , VRAM: 128MB.

Comment: Like GPU in an old Lenovo T61p did not support Windows 10. I dumped it.

Comment: I would suggest to do it in stages : First upgrade to Windows 7, then try Windows 8. Windows 8 drivers might possibly work on Windows 10. An example Windows 7 NVIDIA driver is [here](https://www.nvidia.com/download/driverResults.aspx/8972/en-us) (might not be the latest).

Comment: I upgraded my machine to Windows 8 - worked. But the next upgrade to Windows 10 would not work.

Comment: I will try Windows 8.1 for sure but it will be EOL in January, 2023 so it's not really worth it. Both Chrome and Firefox will not support it for far too long either. I contemplated  installing Linux on it but the person who uses this laptop absolutely needs Microsoft Office and other Windows-only applications, so it's not an option.

Comment: Windows 8 / 8.1 is very end of life, so yes, that is not worth it. Your question was Windows 10 and that is not going to work based on what you said and what I posted.

Comment: A light Linux desktop is an excellent idea to get a few more years of live from the old hardware. But if the person needs Windows software that much (doubtfully but to each its own) then the person must invest in something more current. End of story.

Comment: @ChanganAuto Maybe it's just me but I absolutely hate getting rid of perfectly working hardware. Too bad probably just a hundred of people in the entire world can help me, and all of them work in Microsoft and no one of them is here.

Comment: Me too. That's why I use Linux :)

Comment: @ChanganAuto, e.g., Ubuntu 18.04 is keeping an old 32-bit Acer alive -- great for travel, and if it's lost, damaged or stolen, very little loss.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've not been able to get to the root of the issue but it looks like a critical ACPI incompatibility. There are no power related setting in the BIOS, so there's nothing to adjust in order to fix the issue.

I've installed Windows 8.1 which works fine on it and everything is supported. Unfortunately it's gonna get [EOL](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/faq/windows)'ed in January, 2023, but I want to hope that web browsers will support the OS a little longer.

Answer (score 0):

There is often not concrete information on why very old machines will not run very new operating systems. Computers are usually certified to run a specific operating system and after that I do not see many records being kept about what will not work.

I had a Lenovo T61p laptop with similar NVIDIA GPU. It was certified to run XP, Vista 64-bit and Windows 7 64-bit. I ran it for about 5 years with Windows 7 and it worked well.

It barely ran Windows 8 and would NOT run Windows 10. It was simply too old.

To be specific: It was the lack of Video (GPU) drivers that would not allow Windows 10 to install.

I dumped the machine and moved on and that is a normal outcome for very old machines.

Comment: Also, 3GB of ram may meet the minimum requirements but will REALLY SUCK.  Prepare to have your machine hitting the pagefile ALL OF THE TIME.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas this is not true at all. 32bit Windows works perfectly with this much RAM, it's with a 64bit version that you really need 6GB or more because Windows has to keep two versions of libraries at all times and then 64bit applications consume more RAM.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov - That was only true for earlier versions of Windows, and do not hold true for Windows 10, and especially Windows 11

Comment: I have a 32bit Windows 10 VM and with paging file completely disabled. It works perfectly. I presume you haven't touched a 32bit Windows installation in the past 10 years.

Comment: You presume wrong @ArtemS.Tashkinov (as in I don't run the 32bit version on anything).  The OP said nothing about 32bit windows.  I am glad that it works for you though.